# How to convert an array into a 2D matrix in Lua?

Tags: lua

I have the following array of numbers.

```
arr = {3412323450, 8912745671, 3212367894}
```

I want to convert it into a simple two-dimensional matrix.

```
mat = {
         {3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0},
         {8, 9, 1, 2, 7, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1},
         {3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 4}
}
```

Initially, I would iterate over `arr`, convert it into a string, then split the string, iterate over each string char and convert it back to number storing every row and number in `mat` accordingly. This would be really ugly.

1. Is there a more conventional method to convert an array into a matrix in
   Lua?
2. Is there a luarock package that people use frequently to convert an array to a matrix?

Comment: The *convert to string -> split-> convert back to string* way isn't ugly to me.

Comment: `mat = {}; for i, n in ipairs(arr) do mat[i] = load('return {'..string.gsub(n, '%d', '%0,')..'}')() end`

Comment: I'd rather you answered and explained what does `load` do.

Comment: [load()](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-load) loads a string as Lua function

Comment: Can you please post an answer so I would mark it as solved?

Comment: My comment does not pretend to be a correct answer.  It is just a quick-and-dirty solution.  Try `arr = {123456789, 'os.execute"rm something"'}` to see what may happen.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: "*My comment does not pretend to be a correct answer. It is just a quick-and-dirty solution.*" OK, seriously, this has to stop. Your have personally done this on *many* Lua questions, and this has made the unanswered Lua question list useless. It's been brought up to you in the past, and you have clearly ignored it because you *keep doing it*. A solution is a solution; there is nothing incorrect about one that is "quick-and-dirty". If you truly don't want to take credit for it, then make the post Community Wiki. But sticking it in a comment is worse than doing nothing.

Comment: @NicolBolas - It is OK to post hints, advices, dirty workarounds as comments, not answers. Quality standards for being a "good answer" are rather high on SO.  Create a topic on Meta if you want to discuss it.

Comment: @Egor Yes, but if your comment does indeed solve the problem at hand, a low quality answer is better than none. As pointed out by Nicol, unanswered list is useless because of this. Perhaps a personal guideline could be "Okay, if nobody answers within 3 days, I'll post my answer". Leaving it in the comments is not very helpful.

Comment: @warspyking - Unanswered list is useless because nobody wants to create answers which are exhaustive and verbose.  Short answers, which consist only of code, are often down-voted here.  That's why "comment" is my middle name :-)

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: "*That's why 'comment' is my middle name :-)*" If you do not feel you can contribute productively to Stack Overflow, then it would probably be best for all involved for you to cease contributing at all.

Comment: @Egor Look at my answer. All I gave was code, and a brief explanation of what it's doing. It's not that difficult. While I don't feel you should *stop* contributing, it may be helpful if you began to give answers rather than comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I think converting to a string and grabbing all of the digits is far prettier than the alternatives (massively dividing by 10, or any other elaborate means you can think of). This is especially true if you wrap the operations up in functions, so your conversions are not constantly appearing throughout your code.

```
function Digits(n)
    local digits = {}
    for d in tostring(n):gmatch('%d') do
        digits[#digits+1] = tonumber(d)
    end
    return digits
end

function ArrayToMatrix(array)
    local matrix = {}
    for i,v in ipairs(array) do
        matrix[i] = Digits(v)
    end
    return matrix
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, here is my try.

```
arr = {3412323450, 8912745671, 3212367894}

function arr2matrix(arr)
  local mat = {}
  for i, row in ipairs(arr) do
    mat[i] = {}
    local j = 0
    row_str = string.gsub(row, '%d', '%0 ')
    for c in string.gmatch(row_str, '%S') do
      j = j + 1
      mat[i][j] = tonumber(c)
    end
  end
  return mat
end

-- checking the result
m = arr2matrix(arr)
for i=1, #m do
  for j=1, #m[i] do
    io.write(m[i][j]..',')
  end
  io.write('\n')
end
```

Running the above gives:

```
3,4,1,2,3,2,3,4,5,0,
8,9,1,2,7,4,5,6,7,1,
3,2,1,2,3,6,7,8,9,4,
```